# Python , telethon throwing flood error for adding more than 200 users into telegram channel

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I have tried using InvitetochannelRequest method for adding the users to my telegram channel from csv file ,but not able to add more than 200 users to channel using telethon library. its throwing flood error 
can anybody help me on this

Answer (score 4):

You cant invite more than 200 peoples to channel. Telegram's limits. 
Proof: https://telegram.org/faq_channels#q-how-do-i-add-people-to-my-channel

Comment: A link would make this a better answer

Comment: @matt freak , I want to add users from one channel to other , its very tedious to give link to each user

Comment: Sorry, I meant a link to some documentation where Telegram explain the limit of 200 people. It was a comment for @apepenkov

Comment: [Here you go](https://telegram.org/faq_channels#q-how-do-i-add-people-to-my-channel), @sach

Comment: Thanks @Apepenkov , Is there any way do you know to overcome this ,for script